# Java game a bullet killed all object on the screen

Tags: java

I am trying to make a plane shooting game.

I have a plane with a number of laser(`maxLaser`) and a number of random enemies.

When I create a single random enemy it is fine but when I make a number of enemy I have a tiny problem.

When I shot any of enemy with the bullet(`laser`) kills every enemies on the screen.

I guess I have a problem with two nested loops (`maxLaser` and `maxEnemy`) but I could not figure out.

This is the code I am trying to fix that calculate distance `laser` and `enemy`

```
 public void updatehelicopter(double dt) {

        helicopterSpin = getFrame(0.2, 4);



        // nested loop for kill enemies
        for(int l =0; l<maxHelicopter; l++){
            helicopterPositionX[l] += helicopterVelocityX[l] * dt;
            helicopterPositionY[l] += helicopterVelocityY[l] * dt;


            // if(helicopterActive[l]==true){
            for (int i = 0; i < maxLaser; i++) {
            if (laserActive[i] == true) {
                if (distance(laserPositionX[i], laserPositionY[i], helicopterPositionX[l], helicopterPositionY[l]) < 20* 1.2) {
                    // Destroy the laser
                    laserActive[i] = false;
                    helicopterActive[l]=false;

                    // Create an explosion
                    createExplosion(helicopterPositionX[i], helicopterPositionY[l]);

                    // Create a new random helicopter
                    randomhelicopter();
                }

           }
       }
    }
}
```

The idea is, I want to create 10 enemies and when shot one of them the program that I want to create one more simultaneously.

Here is my Laser and Enemies classes that you can imagine.

Enemy:

```
 Image helicopters;
    Image[] helicopterF = new Image[4];
    Image[] helicopterR = new Image[4];
    Image[] helicopterL = new Image[4];
    Image helicopterImage;

    // helicopter Position
    double[] helicopterPositionX;
    double[] helicopterPositionY;

    double[] helicopterVelocityX;
    double[] helicopterVelocityY;

    double[] helicopterAngle;

    int helicopterSpin;


    boolean helicopterLeft;
    boolean helicopterRight;
    boolean[] helicopterActive;
    int maxHelicopter;
    int numhelicopter ;


    public void inithelicopter() {
        maxHelicopter = 10;
        numhelicopter = maxHelicopter;

        helicopterPositionX = new double[maxHelicopter];
        helicopterPositionY = new double[maxHelicopter];

        helicopterVelocityX= new double[maxHelicopter];
        helicopterVelocityY= new double[maxHelicopter];

        helicopterAngle = new double[maxHelicopter];
        helicopterActive = new boolean[maxHelicopter];

        for(int i =0; i<maxHelicopter;i++){
            helicopterActive[i]=false;
        }




        // Load image
        // helicopterPositionX= 300;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            helicopterF[i] = subImage(helicopters, 0 + i * 300, 0, 300, 300);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            helicopterR[i] = subImage(helicopters, 0 + i * 300 + 1200, 0, 300, 300);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            helicopterL[i] = subImage(helicopters, 0 + i * 300 + 2400, 0, 300, 300);
        }

        // helicopterPositionY= 400;
        // helicopterImage = subImage(spritesheet, 480, 0, 240, 240);
    }




    // Randomly position helicopter
    public void randomhelicopter() {
        for (int i = 0; i < numhelicopter; i++) {


        // Random position
        // random number between lower and upper limit for direction of items
        helicopterPositionX[i] = (int) (Math.random() * (600 - 500)) + 500;
        helicopterPositionY[i] = rand(-500);


        // Random Velocity
        helicopterVelocityX[i] = -20;
        helicopterVelocityY[i] = 80;

        // Random Angle
        helicopterAngle[i] = 40;
            }
        }


    // Function to update 'move' the helicopter
    public void updatehelicopter(double dt) {

        helicopterSpin = getFrame(0.2, 4);



        // 
        for(int l =0; l<maxHelicopter; l++){
            helicopterPositionX[l] += helicopterVelocityX[l] * dt;
            helicopterPositionY[l] += helicopterVelocityY[l] * dt;


            // if(helicopterActive[l]==true){
            for (int i = 0; i < maxLaser; i++) {
            if (laserActive[i] == true) {
                if (distance(laserPositionX[i], laserPositionY[i], helicopterPositionX[l], helicopterPositionY[l]) < 20* 1.2) {
                    // Destroy the laser
                    laserActive[i] = false;
                    helicopterActive[l]=false;

                    // Create an explosion
                    createExplosion(helicopterPositionX[i], helicopterPositionY[l]);

                    // Create a new random helicopter
                    randomhelicopter();
                }

        }
        }
    }


    }

    public void drawhelicopter() {
        // Save the current transform
        for(int i=0; i<maxHelicopter; i++){
        saveCurrentTransform();

        // ranslate to the position of the helicopter
        translate(helicopterPositionX[i], helicopterPositionY[i]);

        // Rotate the drawing context around the angle of the helicopter
        rotate(helicopterAngle[i]);

        // Draw the actual helicopter
        //int i = getAnimationFrame(explosionTimer, explosionDuration, 30);
        drawImage(helicopterF[helicopterSpin], -30, -30, 110, 110);

        // Restore last transform to undo the rotate and translate transforms
        restoreLastTransform();
        }
    }
```

Laser:

```
 Image laserImage;

    double[] laserPositionX;
    double[] laserPositionY;

    // Laser velocity
    double[] laserVelocityX;
    double[] laserVelocityY;

    // Laser Angle
    double[] laserAngle;

    // Laser active
    boolean[] laserActive;

    // Laser Mode
    int laserMode;
    double rapidFireDelay;
    double rapidFireTimer;


    int maxLaser, numLaser;

    // NOTE: try first add 5 different level and if works then you should try make
    // one laser and should cahnge only image
    public void laserInit() {

        maxLaser = 9;
        numLaser = maxLaser;
        laserMode = 0;
        rapidFireDelay = 0.1;



        laserPositionX = new double[maxLaser];
        laserPositionY = new double[maxLaser];

        laserVelocityX = new double[maxLaser];
        laserVelocityY = new double[maxLaser];
        laserAngle = new double[maxLaser];
        laserActive = new boolean[maxLaser];

        for (int i = 0; i < maxLaser; i++) {
            laserActive[i] = false;
        }

        laserImage = subImage(laser, 1536, 0, 512, 512);

    }

    public void fireLaser(double x, double y, double angle) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numLaser; i++) {
            if (laserActive[i] == false) {

                laserPositionX[i] = x;
                laserPositionY[i] = y;

                laserVelocityX[i] = sin(angle) * 350;
                laserVelocityY[i] = -cos(angle) * 350;

                laserAngle[i] = angle;
                // laseractive[i] == true;
                laserActive[i] = true;

                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void fireLaser() {
        // NOTE: check variable of laserpower
        if (laserMode == 0) {
            // Normal Mode
            fireLaser(airplanePositionX, airplanePositionY, airplaneAngle);
        } else if (laserMode == 1) {
            // Scatter Shot
            int inactiveLasers = 0;

            // For all lasers
            for (int i = 0; i < numLaser; i++) {
                // Check if laser is inactive
                if (laserActive[i] == false) {
                    // Count number of inactive lasers
                    inactiveLasers++;
                }
            }

            // Check if at least 3 lasers are free
            if (inactiveLasers >= 3) {
                // Fire three lasers
                fireLaser(airplanePositionX, airplanePositionY, airplaneAngle - 15);
                fireLaser(airplanePositionX, airplanePositionY, airplaneAngle);
                fireLaser(airplanePositionX, airplanePositionY, airplaneAngle + 15);
            }
        } else if (laserMode == 2) {
            // Rapid-Fire Mode
            fireLaser(airplanePositionX, airplanePositionY, airplaneAngle + rand(20.0) - 10);
        }

    }

    public void createLaser() {
        saveCurrentTransform();
        for (int i = 0; i < maxLaser; i++) {

            if (laserActive[i]) {
                saveCurrentTransform();
                translate(laserPositionX[i], laserPositionY[i]);
                rotate(laserAngle[i]);
                drawImage(laserImage, -30, -30, 60, 60);
                restoreLastTransform();
            }
        }
        restoreLastTransform();
    }

    public void laserUpdate(double dt) {

        if (laserMode == 2 && space) {
            // Increment Timer
            rapidFireTimer += dt;

            // If Timer is greater than delay
            if (rapidFireTimer > rapidFireDelay) {
                // Decrement delay
                rapidFireTimer -= rapidFireDelay;

                // Fire laser
                fireLaser();
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < maxLaser; i++) {
            laserPositionX[i] += laserVelocityX[i] * dt;
            laserPositionY[i] += laserVelocityY[i] * dt;
            if (laserPositionX[i] < 0) {
                laserActive[i] = false;

            }
            if (laserPositionX[i] >= width()) {
                laserActive[i] = false;
            }
            if (laserPositionY[i] < 0) {
                laserActive[i] = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

I am not sure how correct I am so can I get your advise?

Externally some class in code:

```
public double distance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
        // Calculate and return the distance
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2-x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2-y1, 2));
    }
```

Comment: What does the method rand(int) do ? `helicopterPositionY[i] = rand(-500);`.

Here: `createExplosion(helicopterPositionX[i], helicopterPositionY[l]);` It should be `l`instead of `i` for X position.

What is the range of `dt` ?

Comment: If you not give rand() number all enemies is been created at the same time -500 is I wanted to give a range for before screen starts. Also I changed but same. The things is that only objects in screen kills together and strait away I can see some other enemies.